# How to get items from a database into a listbox

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to get all the data from my database into a listbox, but at the moment it is only getting the very first row, but when I print the same data, it prints every row. This is what I am attempting to build by populating the listbox. Imagine a listbox that collects data from columns in a table or database, this is how my solution implements

```py
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("TCCAnimalComplaints.db")
connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cursor = connection.cursor()

listData = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM animalcomplaints")
customers = cursor.fetchall()

for name in customers:
    #print('{0}'.format(name[0]))
    customer = '{0}'.format(name[0])
    itemsforlistbox = [customer]

customerSelect=Tk()
sizex = 600
sizey = 400
posx  = 40
posy  = 20
customerSelect.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))
#itemsforlistbox=['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven']

def CurSelect(evt):
    value=str((mylistbox.get(mylistbox.curselection())))
    print (value)

mylistbox=Listbox(customerSelect,width=60,height=10,font=('times',13))
mylistbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',CurSelect)
mylistbox.place(x=32,y=90)

for items in itemsforlistbox:
    mylistbox.insert(END,items)
mainloop()
```

I want the listbox to list every row in the database
instead it only lists the very first row

No errors in python linting.
Expected Outcome: None of the rest of the row data entries in different columns are listed. It is something I am trying to implement.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `items` is set to what you are assuming it has been set to? Also, can you please create a [mcve] that doesn't require a database? You should be able to hard-code `customers` to be the exact values that you're getting from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this example you can see all the power of the listbox widget.
self.rs is a recordset, a tuple of tuple, where every record have three fields.

1. The first filed is the pk,
2. The second field is the name of a fruit
3. The third can be 0 or 1.

We load every record in the listbox but even in a dictionary that is coupling with listbox as listbox index = pk of the record.

We do so to retrive all record data when we click on a listbox row.

after launch the script click on Load button and after try to click or double click on some rows of the listbox and see what happend.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Main(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        f = ttk.Frame()

        ttk.Label(f, text = "Listbox").pack()
        sb = tk.Scrollbar(f,orient=tk.VERTICAL)

        self.lstItems = tk.Listbox(f,
                       relief=tk.GROOVE,
                       selectmode=tk.BROWSE,
                       exportselection=0,
                       height=20,
                       width=50,
                       background = 'white',
                       font='TkFixedFont',
                       yscrollcommand=sb.set,)

        self.lstItems.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.on_item_selected)
        self.lstItems.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.on_item_activated)

        sb.config(command=self.lstItems.yview)

        self.lstItems.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.BOTH, expand =1) 
        sb.pack(fill=tk.Y, expand=1)

        w = ttk.Frame()

        ttk.Button(w, text="Load", command=self.on_load).pack()
        ttk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def on_load(self,):

        self.rs = ((1, 'Apple', 1), (2, 'Pear', 1), (3, 'Banana', 1),
              (4, 'Orange',1), (5, 'Grapes', 0), (6, 'Watermelon', 1),
              (7, 'Plum',1), (8, 'Strawberries', 0),)


        index = 0
        self.dict_items={}

        if self.rs:
            self.lstItems.delete(0, tk.END)

            for i in self.rs:
                self.lstItems.insert(tk.END, i[1])

                if i[2] != 1:
                    self.lstItems.itemconfig(index, {'bg':'light gray'})

                self.dict_items[index] = i[0]
                index += 1

    def on_item_activated(self, evt=None):

        if self.lstItems.curselection():
            index = self.lstItems.curselection()[0]
            print("Double-Button-1 self.lstItems.curselection()[0]: {0}".format(index))


        else:
            messagebox.showwarning(self.parent.title(), "No item selected", parent=self)

    def on_item_selected(self, evt):

        if self.lstItems.curselection():
            index = self.lstItems.curselection()[0]
            pk = self.dict_items.get(index)
            print("ListboxSelect self.dict_items.get(index) = {0}".format(pk))
            print("ListboxSelect self.rs[index]: {0}".format(self.rs[index]))


    def on_close(self):
        self.parent.on_exit()

class App(tk.Tk):
    """Start here"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_exit)

        self.set_title()
        self.set_style()

        frame = Main(self,)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def set_style(self):
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        #('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative')
        self.style.theme_use("clam")


    def set_title(self):
        s = "{0}".format('Simple App')
        self.title(s)

    def on_exit(self):
        """Close all"""
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Simple App", "Do you want to quit?", parent=self):
            self.destroy()               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To populate the `listbox` with all the data from from your db you have to iterate over the records by doing this

```
for items in customers:
    mylistbox.insert(END,items)
```

then the records will be inserted in the `listbox`. Adding below function to it is not needed.

```
for name in customers:
#print('{0}'.format(name[0]))
customer = '{0}'.format(name[0])
itemsforlistbox = [customer]
```

Have also organised your for it to be readable.

**FULL CODE**

```
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3




def CurSelect(evt):
    value=str((mylistbox.get(mylistbox.curselection())))
    print (value)



connection = sqlite3.connect("TCCAnimalComplaints.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
listData = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM animalcomplaints")
customers = cursor.fetchall()




customerSelect=Tk()

sizex = 600
sizey = 400
posx  = 40
posy  = 20
customerSelect.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))
#itemsforlistbox=['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven']


mylistbox=Listbox(customerSelect,width=60,height=10,font=('times',13))
mylistbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',CurSelect)
mylistbox.place(x=32,y=90)

for items in customers:
    mylistbox.insert(END,items)

mainloop()
```